# Matching indices with a corresponding identifier in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, join, merge

I have a situation where I want to match some indices in one dataframe to there corresponding ids in another dataframe. 
My df1 looks like this :

```
  id
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

my df2 looks like this :

```
  id_df2
0 1234
1 2222
2 3333
3 3344
```

Now I want to match the index columns in both the data frames and get the value from df2. The output should look like this :

```
  id id_df2
0  1   1234
1  2   2222
2  3   3333
3  4   3344
```

The thing is to match the pandas index columns that represents the row index for both the data frames. Net net I want to perform the following:

Match pandas default index column from df1 to pandas default index column in df2 to get the id from df2

Comment: You could look at using something like `pd.concat`

Comment: If need something else, let me know.

Comment: @Josmoor98: but I have some more columns as well in my df2, I do not want them in my final dataset.

Comment: @jezrael : That does not answer my question. My situation is different, I do want to append data, I need have my ids mapped with the indices.

Comment: @Django0602 - Why is `id=1` in final data?

Comment: Possibly include a more complete example of your current data and what you expect the output to be

Comment: @jezrael: from my df1, for 0 index the value in id is 1 and then to match it with df2 with index 0 the id_df2 would be 1234 hence the final output for index 0 will be 1 and 1234 as shown in my post.

Comment: ok, why not match second, thitd, four row?

Comment: @Josmoor98: added more description, if that helps.

Comment: @jezrael: we have to match all the rows. It will start from the 0 index and will run until 4999 which is my last row.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your current output. From your description, shouldn't all the values from `id` and `id_df2` be in the output?

Comment: @Josmoor98: updated my output. all the rows should be there.

Comment: In that case, the suggested answer should solve your problem. Are the indices from both dataframes matching? i.e. `pd.concat([id, id_df2], axis=1)`

Comment: @Josmoor98: yes they match. but as I said if I have a situation where I have more columns in my data frame then pd.concat will fetch all other columns as well. I do not want that.

Comment: Are your column names `id` and `id_df2`?

Comment: I understand, need `pd.concat([df1['id'], df2['id_df2']], axis=1)`